# Merge two text files based on some condition

Tags: bash, unix, sed

File1: Each record starts with '~' and a Number like below & ends with the same. Each record has eight lines between the start and end line, with some '_'.

```
     ~1
     001
     COMON
     _
     98273497335
     _
     _
     003
     +7346542347
     ~1
     ~2
     001
     .
     .
     ~2.........so on
```

File2: It contains default values for each record like below. It contains only one record. Each record from File1 should be compared to File2 and all '_' to be replaced by the default value in File2 with respect to that position.

```
    ~
    001
    COMON
    0000000000
    0
    00
    00000
    +0.0
    +0000000000
    ~
```

OUTPUT File: The '_' from File1 should be replaced by the default value of File2 in the corresponding position of the record.

```
   ~1
 001
 COMON
 0000000000
 98273497335
 00
 00000
 003
 +7346542347
 ~1
 ~2
 001
 .
 .
 ~2.........so on
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: well, I don't have much idea about shell scripting. once I got the idea I could implement and then I would reply some sort of solutions by my own. I hope by the time I 'll get some help here...

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the question, the requirement was clear, with sample input and output. "Lacking research", perhaps, but not "too broad" at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { line[NR] = $1; next } 
    { print ($1 == "_" ? line[(FNR - 1) % 10 + 1] : $1) }' file2 file1
```

`NR == FNR` targets the first file. Read and save the 10 lines from file2, using the line number `NR` as the key.

The second block is for the second file, due to `next` in the first block. If the first field is "_", then use the substitute value for that line, `(FNR - 1) % 10 + 1` produces the sequence `1..10 1..10 1..10` etc., so the corresponding line from the lookup array is used.

Comment: thanks, Tom..I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user8552135 no problem, does it do what you want?

Comment: @TomFenech I can see OP didn't accept your answer, but I tested it and it works as requested by OP. Thanks. It was interesting solution.